# Automatically set table name prefix according to other field in PowerDesigner

Tags: database-design

I'm working with PowerDesigner 16.5 and I have a PDM generated out of its corresponding LDM. The table names are inherited from the LDM and I'm fine with them, but I would like to generate the DDL with a table name prefix according the dimensional type (dimension or fact) of each. At this point I don't mind if it is done just in the DDL generation or in the name-to-code translation.

So a mydimensiontable table would have a code as **CREATE TABLE dim_mydimensiontable** and myfacttable would have a code as **CREATE TABLE fact_myfacttable** ... If not possible with the dimensional type, maybe a custom field could work as well for me.

Is it possible? Please note, I'm an experience data model designer but my experience with heavy customization/tweaking/hacking in PowerDesigner is very very limited, so I would need almost step by step explanations. :-/

Thank you very much in advance.

Nacho